# LocationTrack has no default constructor

Tags: java, android, service

Всем привет,имеется класс для отслеживания местоположения,инициализирую так.

```
    private static final String TAG = "GPS Tracker";
public LocationTrack(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    getLocation();
    Log.d(TAG, "GPS трекер запущен");
}
```

Попытался добавить его в манифест:

```
<service android:name=".LocationTrack" />
```

Выдает ошибку вида:

```
LocationTrack has no default constructor
```

Что я делаю не так?И как заставить работать его в фоне?

Comment: `default constructor` - это конструктор без аргументов

Comment: @Komdosh, что значит это я понял,я не могу понять,что ему не нравится у меня в коде...Ибо инициализацию то я делаю `public LocationTrack(Context mContext)`

Comment: для сервиса нужен `public LocationTrack()`

Comment: @NasdomlanUrban3p, Ваш сервис будет инициализировать система, а не Вы. И для этого ей нужен конструктор без параметров - Вы должны объявить такой или убрать параметры у существующего. Контекстом сервиса является сам сервис, поэтому поле `mContext` не нужно - везде где он нужен можно использовать `this` или `LocationTrack.this` (во вложенных классах обязательно второй вариант)